# Determine if a field problem

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, field-theory

Determining when something's a field is often quite straightforward but in this case I'm stuck.  From the first statement it's quite clear to me that the field isn't the complex field, since it would certainly have roots otherwise.  but the way the question is worded and how they defined multiplication makes things very confusing for me.  I'm hoping to get some insight into this problem and to get some assistance in finding the mulitplicative inverse.  With this I can prove the rest.

> Let F be a field such that $$p(x):=x^2+x+1\neq 0$$
>
> for all $x\in F$.  Let $G=F \times F$ with elements written $(a,b)=a+jb$, $a,b\in F $, for a formal symbol $j$.  Define addition componentwise
>
> $$(a+jb)+(c+jd)=(a+c)+j(b+d)$$,
>
> and define multiplication by the rule that $j^2+j+1=0$:
>   $$(a+jb)(c+jd)=(ac-bd)+j(ad+bc-bd)$$.
>
> Show that $G$ with these additions and mulitplications is a field.

Comment: Did you notice that $G$ is isomorphic to the quotient ring $F[x] / p(x)$?

Answer (score 0):

In order to find the multiplicative inverse of $a+bj$, solve the equation $(a+bj)(x+yj)=1$, that is, solve the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}ax-by=1\\ay+bx-by=0,\end{array}\right.$$

It turns out that your field is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: You are assuming $F = \mathbb{R}$ but it may be finite like the integers mod 2 or $\mathbb{Q}$ which would give the extension $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ neither of which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField You are right. I was assuming that.